# Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error Using Access

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook, ms-office

I'm trying to send automated emails through outlook from Access, but I've run into an issue where if a user does not have their email open already, I will get the `Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error`.  I'm using a late binding to avoid the .dll's since I have users on both Office 2003 and Office 2010.

Is there anyway around this error and still allowing the emails to go through?  Or possibly "forcing" outlook to open if it is not already?

Thanks in advance

Sure thing, here's the whole code to the email.

When I step through it fails at `Set appOutlookRec = .Recipients.Add(myR!Email)`

```
Option Explicit
Function SendEmail(strDep, strIssue, strPriority, strDate, strDesc, wonum, user)

Const olMailItem = 0
Const olTo = 1
Const olCC = 2
Dim sqlVar As String
Dim strSQL As String

If strDep = "Cycle" Then

ElseIf strDep = "Fabrication" Then
    sqlVar = "Fabricator"
ElseIf strDep = "Facility" Then
    sqlVar = "Facility"
ElseIf strDep = "Gage" Then
    sqlVar = "Gage"
ElseIf strDep = "IT" Then
    sqlVar = "IT"
ElseIf strDep = "Machine Shop" Then
    sqlVar = "Machine_Shop_Manager"
ElseIf strDep = "Safety" Then
    sqlVar = "Safety"
ElseIf strDep = "Maintenance" Then
    sqlVar = "Maintenance_Manager"
ElseIf strDep = "Supplies Request" Then
    sqlVar = "Supplies"
Else:
End If

Dim myR As Recordset

'Refers to Outlook's Application object
Dim appOutlook As Object
'Refers to an Outlook email message
Dim appOutlookMsg As Object
'Refers to an Outlook email recipient
Dim appOutlookRec As Object

'Create an Outlook session in the background
Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Create a new empty email message
Set appOutlookMsg = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Using the new, empty message...
With appOutlookMsg    

strSQL = "SELECT Email FROM Employees WHERE " & sqlVar & " = True"
Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Do While Not myR.EOF
Set appOutlookRec = .Recipients.Add(myR!Email)
appOutlookRec.Type = olTo
myR.MoveNext
Loop

strSQL = "SELECT Email FROM Employees WHERE '" & user & "' = Username"

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Set appOutlookRec = .Recipients.Add(myR!Email)
appOutlookRec.Type = olCC

.Subject = wonum

.Body = "Department: " & strDep & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Issue is at: " & strIssue & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Priority is: " & strPriority & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Complete by: " & strDate & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Description: " & strDesc

.Send

End With

Set myR = Nothing
Set appOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set appOutlook = Nothing
Set appOutlookRec = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: If you show some code then it's easier to make suggestions.

Comment: What is the value of `myR!Email` when you get that error?

Comment: `Debug.Print myR!Email` outputs my correct email address xxx.xxx@xxx.com

Comment: BTW are you referring to the line above olTo or olCC?

Comment: Good Point it is olTo.  It enters my.EOF loop, moves to debug, then to Set appOutlookRec, then the next step is the error.

Comment: Before you execute the do loop can you put a break point there and check if `appOutlook` is not nothing? Try adding doevents after the `CreateObject` I tested your code without the database and it works fine...

Comment: I added `Debug.Print appOutlook` and it returned Outlook in the immediate window.  But I'm unfamiliar with adding a doevent after `CreateObject`...  could you clarify?  Should I be setting `appOutlookRec = CreateObject` first or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try using .Save before .Send. I was scheduling outlook code through MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

So what appears to be happening is your reference to the Outlook.Application is- well. stagnant- for lack of a better word. You don't just want to create an Outlook Session - you want to connect to an existing running application.

I'm not a pro on Access, so I'll just suggest generalities: Try to Obtain a handle on an already running Outlook Application, otherwise have it open Outlook (Give it time to fully startup using sleep/wait and a DoEvents command) and try again to obtain that handle.

I was using `VBA` within Outlook attempting to read the sender names (also getting the same error). Traced it down to my method of obtaining the current outlook application handle. 
Instead of:

```
Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application");
```

I had to:

```
Set appOutlook = ThisOutlookSession;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After the line `Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`, add the following:

```
set NS = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
```